# Why typecasting operator doesn't work with inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, operator-overloading

I have two classes:

```
struct B {};
struct D {
  operator B& ();
};
```

When I do;

```
b = d; // B b; ... D d;
```

Result is as per expectation where `D::operator B&()` is invoked ([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/H0V8r)).

If the `D` is changed to,

```
struct D : B {
  operator B& ();
};
```

then `D::operator B&()` is not invoked ([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/iYoe9)). Is `B::B(const B&)` is finding a better candidate in `D` then `D::operator B&()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `D` derives from `B`, there is an implicit automatic conversion from `D` to `B`. This has higher precedence than a user-defined conversion operator.